# Update QSqlTableModel on updation of Sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, qt4

I am having one QSqlTableModel which has one Sqlite database table being linked to it.
My database table can be updated via model or directly from other source.

How can i refresh my model to fetch updated data from table whenever that particular table is updated without using select() function.

```
QSqlTableModel * dbEmployeeModel = new QSqlTableModel(this, db); // db refers Sqlite db connection

dbEmployeeModel->setTable("EMP");
```

I want my dbEmployeeModel to be updated whenever there is a change in EMP table in database without using dbEmployeeModel->select()

Comment: Why do you not want to use `->select()`?

Comment: The instant at which updation of table EMP will occur is not known prior to me. So, i dont know in advance where to put select() statement in my code to update the model.

Comment: Who updates that table? Your program, other programs you control, or third-party programs?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621564/concurrency-using-qt-and-sqlite-databases